# Как получить access_token от нового ads.vk.com кабинета?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, token

Всем привет.
Был старый кабинет https://vk.com/ads все работало!
Стал новый рекламный кабинет https://ads.vk.com

Не могу получить access_token
Заранее всем благодарен!

```
url = 'https://ads.vk.com/api/v2/oauth2/token.json'
client_secret = ''
client_id = ''

requests.post(url + '%3F' + f'grant_type=client_credentials' + f'%26' + f'client_id={client_id}' + f'%26' + f'client_secret={client_secret}',
    #headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    ).json()
```

ответ

```
{'error': {'code': 'auth_required', 'message': 'No authentication'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post надо отправлять в data, а не в ссылке

```
import requests


payload = {
    'client_id': 'client_id',
    'client_secret': 'client_secret',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

res = requests.post('https://ads.vk.com/api/v2/oauth2/token.json', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

client_id и client_secret получаем в личном кабинете